# Changing GitLab CI Multirunner executor after initial configuration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am reading through [GitLab CI Multirunner documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/#selecting-the-executor) where it walks one through how to set up a GitLab CI Multirunner executor, but I can't seem to find anything about changing the executor once initially set, either in the docs or searching online. Is this supported?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The configuration is written to `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` which you can edit with your favourite editor, after which you need to reload or restart the runner service.

Here's [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) for the GitLab Runner `config.toml` file.